# How to load rvm installed on /usr/local

Tags: ruby, rvm, rvm-capistrano, rvmsudo

I have a issue installing rvm in a server.

I've installed rvm with a sudo user on  /usr/local
but when I enter with another user I get this

```
rvm
No command 'rvm' found, but there are 26 similar ones
rvm: command not found
```

By the way that user is on the rvm group.

Comment: Where exactly `rvm` executable is located (check with `whereis rvm` or `which rvm`)?

Comment: rvm: /usr/local/rvm /home/horacio/.rvm/bin/rvm

Comment: Uninstall rvm and do a sudo install again.

Comment: `/usr/local/rvm` can’t be found because `/usr/local` is not on the path. Move the executable to `/usr/local/bin`: `mv /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm`.

Comment: Thank guys I've uninstall and delete all references on bashrc, profile and /etc/rvm and install it again with sudo and works thanks @c0de222 and @ mudasobwa